# Can you open this vault?

Tags: story

Your rich and famous riddler friend has frequent memory loss since he's getting older and older.
In order to prevent himself from forgetting everything, he writes everything as a riddle in his diary, and 
he has all his goods placed in different vaults. One morning, he wants to show you the 
brand new watch he bought the day before. Both of you go in the vaults room. The old riddler then gives you
his diary, approaches the vaults and tells you :

> "Mmh, let's see the vault's number."

You open his diary under the section "Jewels & Watches", and read out loud:

> **"The number of the vault is a four digits number : there's nothing between you and I."**

Your friend mumble:

> "An easy one to start, obviously. Alright, and the combination, please? The corresponding riddle might be right under the first one."

And indeed, it is.

> To find the combination, you will need to fill the blanks of the following sentence by numbers, which put side by side, will help you open the vault.
>    But be careful, the final sentence has to make sense...
>   **This sentence must have ________ vowels and ________ consonants.**

You see your friend thinking, and after a couple of minutes, he says:

> "Damn, this one is harder than I thought. I don't know if you will see my new wristwatch today, my friend..."

Confidently, you reassure him:

> "Don't worry, I know exactly the combination!"

So, **what is the vault's number and what is its combination?**

Comment: So the combination isn't 1326, because there is 13 vowels and 26 consonants in that sentence, but it says that it "is harder than I thought"?

Comment: @GintasK But if you put in thirteen and twenty-six, the number of vowels and consonants change.

Comment: @PartyHatPanda it doesn't say that you have to put the numbers in as words?

Comment: @GintasK True, but as you said then it wouldn't be much of a riddle then. I assumed it must be necessary to do so - otherwise we would not be here!

Comment: You should add the fact that y is considered a vowel as it could throw people off.  Or at least some sort of hint that will allow you determine that you should treat y as a vowel, e.g A warm up sentence like, 'I spy ten vowels in this sentence.'

Comment: I didn't downvote, just a suggestion for improvement, I am from Australia and we generally don't consider 'y' a vowel here (at least I don't.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The vault number could be:

> **2109** - credits @AndrewF

And the combination is:

> **2138**
>
>  Because the sentence
>  "This sentence must have twenty-one vowels and thirty-eight consonants."
>  Consists of 21 vowels and 38 consonants.
>
>  P.S. Assuming letter **Y** is a **vowel**.

Comment: Are we assuming 'y' is a vowel? If so, that will work!

Comment: Well, I assumed that it is, it says "sometimes" on wikipedia though :D

Comment: This is it, nice! And, yes, `y` is considered as a vowel here. Good job!

Answer (score 8):

A shot in the dark here

"The number of the vault is a four digits number : there's nothing between you and I."

> 2109  U is the 21st letter of the alphabet and i is the 9th

This sentence must have ________ vowels and ________ consonants.

> 2138 assuming y as a vowel from Gintas K, can find nothing else that fits

Comment: Nice, you got the first part! Here, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a partial answer, but I'm unsure about the first part.

> **"The number of the vault is a four digits number: there's nothing between you and I"**
>
> > I'm unsure about this one.
>
> **This sentence must have ___________ vowels and __________ consonants**
>
> > I believe the first part is eighteen, and the second part is thirty. Unless I did my addition wrong. Which I wouldn't be surprised by.
> >   Combination = 18 - 30

Comment: This is incorrect because there is 26 constanants in the sentence and more than four in eighteen and thirty

Comment: I just realized I wasn't counting the 2nd number. Back to the drawing board.